# Azure WebApp to Virtual Machine SQL server Connection is slow

Tags: sql-server, azure, iis, virtual-machine

I have deployed the web site to Azure Cloud (WEBAPP) and the SQL DB to Virtual Machine that I have created on Azure.

Web App is MVC 5 and using EF6 to connect to SQL DB, Before I migrated it was fast but after the migration the database open connection is very slow.

I did some research on how to create a Azure VNet to move both WebApp and VM under same Virtual Network (VNet), But I couldn't do it . If anybody had this issue and knows any clues or directions that would be great.

I also tried this: [Slow Database Connection from Azure Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397111/slow-database-connection-from-azure-web-application) But couldn't resolve my issue.

I assume the solution is to create a VNet and move both under the same VNet, But couldn't find any articles. Please share your thoughts,...

Comment: Please define "it was fast" and "is very slow"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the database from a virtual machine. Databases need memory and fast storage. You are not telling what kind of server you are using. Upgrade the machine to decent memory and premium storage. Next check if all your resources are on the same azure site (region). If not move the to one region. You say you can't put them in the same vnet, what is the error or reason? If you can solve that the machines will get better connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Peter, I think your point is right. I upgraded the VM from 2 cores - 4 cores , (same memory size 14GB).

For the VNet I have created two sub-nets for front end and back end ,
 But my issue is how can I link Azure WebApp interface and VM interface under those two sub-nets. Please keep in mind I have linked my external domain to WebApp public IP ( CNAME , A Record) . Thanks